# I want to know the condithion in which AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error occur when I regist C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am investigating `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error which occurs when I regist C2DM by using [the ChromeToPhone application](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/).

[The C2DM reference document](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) says as below. But actual behaviour, however, is a little different from that document. I have some questions about this.

> AUTHENTICATION_FAILED : Bad password. The application should ask the user to enter his/her password, and let user retry manually later. Fix on the device side

---

[1] Change the password

1. Change the password of Google account by using the PC.
2. My android phone shows `Sync error` at the view of Settings::Accounts & sync::(My Google account).
3. I succeed in the registration of c2dm on my android phone by using the ChromeToPhone application.
4. Next, Reboot the android phone.
5. The C2DM registration returns the `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error.

1st question:
I think it should return `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error on step3. But Why I succeed?

---

[2] Delete the account

1. Delete the Google account by using the PC.
2. My android phone shows `Sync OK` at the Settings::Accounts & sync::(My Google account).
3. Next, Reboot the android phone.
4. The C2DM registration returns the `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error.

2nd question:
[2] is not the conditon of 'Bad password'. Do you know another conditon that `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` will be returned like this?

---

[3] Multi account

1. Change the password of Google account.
2. Add another valid Google account to my android phone.
3. Reboot the android phone.
4. The C2DM registration returns the `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error.

3rd question:
Does the primary Google account on the phone have to be valid to succeed in the C2DM registration?

---

Thank you for reading this question. Please answer my question, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "[1] Change the password" use case, step 3. Did you try to uninstall ChromeToPhone from device completely, install it again. Would it register C2DM successfully after that? If you didn't do that it could have C2DM token already available that's why it doesn't bother about changed password.

Comment: Thank you Fedor. I did'nt uninstall ChromeToPhone on step3. I think that the C2DM token become invalid automatically.